# What does it mean for armor to increase "evasive fire damage"?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found the following armor, and I'm not sure what all of its modifiers mean:

[image]

What is "evasive fire damage"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It increases the damage of the Demon Hunter skill [**Evasive Fire**.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/evasive-fire)

Comment: Oh, "Evasive Fire", not "evasive fire".  Sigh, thanks!